# Should I use a GLM or an ANCOVA?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, ancova

I'm studying leaf litter decay rates of two plant species, as affected by different treatments. As I need to compare the effect of the treatments, my director suggested me the use of an ANCOVA, with time as the covariate. But one of the assumptions is the slopes homogeinity, and when I fit my data to an ANCOVA this assumption isn't satisfied.

A co-worker advised me to use a generalized linear mixed model (random effect been the species - I only have 2!), but will this allow me to compare the slopes between treatments?

My response variable is remaining weight, but I can also use proportions (remaining weight/initial weight) or the ln-transformations. This brings me to my next question, which probability distribution is convenient to use?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think your colleague is confused about what a GLM does. At least the first way to try to remedy your problem is to include an interaction term in your ANCOVA regression. GLM is for when you want to model the $\lambda$ of a conditional Poisson distribution or the $p$ of a conditional binomial distribution (to give two examples).

Comment: @Dave This comment could really be an answer. Do you want to make it one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your colleague is confused about what a GLM does. At least the first way to try to remedy your problem is to include an interaction term in your ANCOVA regression. GLM is for when you want to model the $\lambda$ of a conditional Poisson distribution or the $p$ of a conditional binomial distribution (to give two examples). Including an interaction between the group variable and the ANCOVA covariate will allow for each group to have its own slope.

You might want to explicitly model a particular type of distribution like a binomial or a Poisson, anyway, while using such an interaction term. While GLMs support this quite naturally (both in terms of the mathematical theory and the implementation in software), it is not self-evident that you need to use a link function, and the link function won’t even give the groups different slopes, which requires an interaction.